# Were there any real-life 'escape rooms' before Real Escape Game in Japan?

Tags: puzzle-history

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_room#History), the first official 'escape room' was [Real Escape Game](http://realescapegame.jp/) in Japan. However, I can't find anything about a physical escape-the-room type activity before that, and I seem to recall having been to something of the sort before 2007, when Real Escape Game was developed. (I keep thinking Wannado City, but I don't think that's it.)

So: **were there any escape-the-room type games before 2007, even if not marketed as an 'escape room'?**

Comment: Crystal maze might count - for the 'mystery' rooms you have to find objects to solve a puzzle to unlock the door - that started in 1990

Comment: (Are we talking about real life or video games or both?)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - I mentioned in the title 'real-life', and 'physical' in the body.

Comment: You might be thinking of the catacombs. But, I heard that Budapest had quite a big market in escape rooms, so if you want to focus your research, Budapest might be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

[According to this site](http://escapegameslondon.co.uk/escape-rooms-through-an-americans-eyes/), "one of the first escape rooms developed in Silicon Valley, California in 2006".

I thought it was a Hungarian invention, as they are extremely popular here, and many people come here from the UK for example.

Comment: The Hungarian comment reminded me of this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92988/finding-good-escape-rooms-in-budapest which also says "Silicon Valley 2006"